# During character generation should all PC have the same number of terms?

Tags: character-creation, traveller, mongoose-traveller-2

When generating characters for Traveller is it normal to make all players have the same number of terms or set a limit on the maximum number of terms allowed? Or will the negative effects of age balance/deter players enough to not make it a problem that one character has only a few terms and another have many?

I'm using MGT2 and did not find anything about the subject in the book. Which is not to say it is not there, just that I did not find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not normal, at least in my experience. The idea of the system is that you get a range of ages, backgrounds and experience rather than a bunch of "level 1" beginners.

In my campaigns the groups have ranged from single term youngsters to 50 year old 30 year marine veterans. This has added a lot to the role playing within the group.

In real life a crew would not all be the same age so I can't see why a role playing crew would be a homogeneous group either.

Comment: I haven't played the Mongoose version, but this was also the case in the original Traveller -- then, there was an end point to the pre-generation process, as I recall (haven't played in 6-7 years), which tended to automatically kick out some characters with little experience, while letting others have lots of skills and assets.

Comment: @ZeissIkon In classic Traveller characters had a chance of dying each term they didn't muster out, and additionally had a chance of being forced out of the career if they rolled poorly enough of their commission/promotion rolls. MGT1 replaced the fatal failure with a being forced out of a career with a minor penalty, which made it much more viable to create a super-competent ancient character. I've not looked at how MGT2 does it, yet; I imagine it could go either way.